# Scraping multiple pages with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, nokogiri

I'm writing a Ruby CLI where I have to list coffee shops and then the user picks one to display its info via scraping with Nokogiri and open-uri.  However, the info is coming from their own respective webpages with this information.

Here is the webpage I'm using: https://cincinnatiusa.com/article/9-hot-coffee-shops

Here is one of the 9 webpages I need to pull info from: https://cincinnatiusa.com/eat-and-drink/carabello-coffee

Here's my code for scraping just one of the pages specifically:

```
  def self.scrape_shops
    url = "https://cincinnatiusa.com/article/9-hot-coffee-shops"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    shops = doc.css(".article-body h2").each do |shop|
    name = shop.text.strip
    BestCoffeeCinci::Shop.new(name)
    end 
  end

  def self.scrape_info
    url = "https://cincinnatiusa.com/eat-and-drink/carabello-coffee"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    address = doc.css(".address").text
    hours = doc.css(".hours").text
    description = doc.css(".full-description").text
    binding.pry
    end
  end
```

How can I scrape the addresses, hours, and descriptions of each coffee shop while using different webpages, without having to list each individual webpage?  Thanks!

Comment: Each page has a different structure, so you'll need to define this in more abstract terms if you want it that way. Consider using YAML as a config format, for example.

Comment: As @tadman wrote, each page implements different selectors for the same information.  One way to handle this is to write a `case` statement (aka `switch` statement in other languages), where you would `try` to locate a css selector like `.address` and if none is found, you would `try` to locate a different selector until you find a match.  This isn't especially performant code, but it will allow you to DRY up your code and expand to other sites in the future.

Comment: You can use a yaml file to config for each page, in this case you will define the xpath for each info you would like to extract.

Comment: Your question is very broad. We don't know your expertise level so writing a clear and concise answer would result in writing a tutorial, which is off-topic. Having written big spiders for companies doing SEO, including one that searched a Fortune 50 company's suite of sites, it takes code that can be modified without shutting down the spider allowing dynamic reconfiguring as it runs to let you fine-tune searches and reduce bad data. That's not easily explained in an answer.